# WPF animation - what happens in the end?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-7.0

I am trying to run different animations on different button clicks to animate same properties but it works only partially (see: [WPF animation - can only animate one property if running second animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122868/wpf-animation-can-only-animate-one-property-if-running-second-animation))

Hence I have a more general question - what happens to a WPF animation after it ends? Does it release resources? Can I completely disregard it after it is done or should I somehow make sure it releases resources?

Comment: The code you link to is referencing an existing storyboard. So the answer is nothing happens to it. It's a private member references it's parent window. If it would be if it worked. No resources to free.

Comment: yeah I somehow enjoy watching SO sink in past 3 yrs. although it is against my interest. of course the answer is much more involved than many of you think. animation does not "vanish" in the end. It continue to keep the properties modified (as my other question shows). there are apparently 2 sets of properties for everything animated - the actual eg window H/W as in my other question and animated. and until you *remove* animation from control it actively *holds* it. I just wanted to hear details from someone who actually knows stuff

Comment: You have seemingly not read the documentation, especially not that of the FillBehavior property.

Comment: Keeping the value on the dependency property set does not involve any resource. It's just setting the dependency property. It isn't some mysterious extra copy of the dependency property. You asked about resources. Nobody gets any points for comments.

Comment: it could keep a timer running for example.. a brush.. things can consume GPU rendering resource due to design limitations or bugs.. lots of things can be happening.. how do you know it doesnt.